# Accessing inventory host variable in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

In Ansible 2.1, I have a role being called by a playbook that needs access to a host file variable.  Any thoughts on how to access it?

I am trying to access the `ansible_ssh_host` in the `test1` section of the following inventory `host` file:

```
[test1]
test-1 ansible_ssh_host=abc.def.ghi.jkl ansible_ssh_port=1212

[test2]
test2-1 ansible_ssh_host=abc.def.ghi.mno ansible_ssh_port=1212

[test3]
test3-1 ansible_ssh_host=abc.def.ghi.pqr ansible_ssh_port=1212
test3-2 ansible_ssh_host=abc.def.ghi.stu ansible_ssh_port=1212

[all:children]
test1
test2
test3
```

I have tried accessing the role in the following fashions:

```
{{ hostvars.ansible_ssh_host }}
```

and

```
{{ hostvars.test1.ansible_ssh_host }}
```

I get this error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVars object' has no attribute 'ansible'"}
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You are on the right track about `hostvars`.
This [magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables) is used to access information about other hosts.

`hostvars` is a hash with inventory hostnames as keys.
To access fields of each host, use `hostvars['test-1']`, `hostvars['test2-1']`, etc.

`ansible_ssh_host` is [deprecated](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) in favor of `ansible_host` since 2.0.
So you should first remove "_ssh" from inventory hosts arguments (i.e. to become "ansible_user", "ansible_host", and "ansible_port"), then in your role call it with:

```
{{ hostvars['your_host_group'].ansible_host }}
```

Comment: spaciba- I tried that syntax but i think it was not working because of a typo on my side

Comment: You can access the `ansible_host` of the local machine by doing `hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_host`

Comment: There's no need to use `hostvars` at all, I'm able to use `ansible_host` variable directly

Comment: That link has now moved to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables

Answer (score 35):

```
[host_group]
host-1 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.0.21 node_name=foo
host-2 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.0.22 node_name=bar

[host_group:vars]
custom_var=asdasdasd
```

You can access host group vars using:

```
{{ hostvars['host_group'].custom_var }}
```

If you need a specific value from specific host, you can use:

```
{{ hostvars[groups['host_group'][0]].node_name }}
```

Answer (score 30):

You should be able to use the variable name directly

```
ansible_ssh_host
```

Or you can go through hostvars without having to specify the host literally
by using the [magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables) `inventory_hostname`

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_ssh_host
```

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with this, too. My specific setup is: Your host.ini (with the modern names):

```
[test3]
test3-1 ansible_host=abc.def.ghi.pqr ansible_port=1212
test3-2 ansible_host=abc.def.ghi.stu ansible_port=1212
```

plus a play fill_file.yml

```
---
- remote_user: ec2-user
  hosts: test3
  tasks:
   - name: fill file
     template:
       src: file.j2
       dest: filled_file.txt
```

plus a template file.j2 , like

```
{% for host in groups['test3'] %}
   {{ hostvars[host].ansible_host }}
{% endfor %}
```

This worked for me, the result is

```
abc.def.ghi.pqr
abc.def.ghi.stu
```

I have to admit it's ansible 2.7, not 2.1. The template is a variation of an example in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html.

The accepted answer didn't work in my setup. With a template

```
{{ hostvars['test3'].ansible_host }}
```

my play fails with "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: \"hostvars['test3']\" is undefined" .

Remark: I tried some variations, but failed, occasionally with "ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVars object has no element "; Some of this might be explained by what they say. in https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13343#issuecomment-160992631

> hostvars emulates a dictionary [...]. hostvars is also lazily loaded

Comment: `my play fails with "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: \"hostvars['test3']\" is undefined" `

this is because you don't have a host `test3`. it will work with 
`{{ hostvars['test3-1'].ansible_host }}` or `{{ hostvars['test3-2'].ansible_host }}`

Answer (score 2):

I've found also a nice and simple way to address hostsvars [right on one of Ansible's Github issues](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31679#issuecomment-336673272)

Looks like you can do this as well:

```
 - debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_ssh_host }}"
```

Comment: This has been deprecated to become "ansible_host"

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot this note was very useful for me! 
Was able to send the variable defined under /group_var/vars in the ansible playbook
as indicated below.

tasks:
    - name: check service account password expiry 
    - command:

```
sh /home/monit/get_ldap_attr.sh {{ item }} {{ LDAP_AUTH_USR }}
```