# Ansible: Access set_fact variables across hosts blocks during playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-template

**[NOTE]:** This is not like accessing other hosts' yaml data like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027847/accessing-inventory-host-variable-in-ansible-playbook). This is setting my own variable during execution and want to access it later

I am using `ansible-playbook` to perform some task on 2 vm pools.

Assume that I have only one host in `vms1` pool. 
And I try to get the hostname from that system dynamically and I want to reuse the same variable across the other `hosts` block in the same file.

I am getting the error saying,

> FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined
>   variable. **The error was: 'myHostname' is undefined**

My playbook yml file looks somewhat like this,

```
- hosts: vms1
  tasks:
    - name: Getting file list
      shell: ls /my/path/
      register: shellOutput

    - set_fact:
        fileList: "{{ shellOutput.stdout }}"

- hosts: vms2
  tasks:
    - name: Get file list
      shell: "echo {{ fileList }} >> /tmp/hostFileList.txt"
```

Comment: `set_fact` sets **a fact** not a variable.　"*This is setting my own variable during execution and want to access it later*" ー you can't do it. You can set a fact for some dummy host and access it later with `hostvars`.

Comment: @techraf : hostvars['dummy']: "{{ shellOutput.stdout }}" like this?

Comment: No, you'd need to use [`add_host` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html) and set the variable.